# Knex raw query not working postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to make the following semi-raw knex query:

```
knex.raw('select sum(invoice_price * quantity) from "localhost:3000".order_item').where({cart_session: 'some_session'}).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.rows[0].sum);
});
```

However, I keep getting the error: `knex.raw(...).where is not a function`.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `raw` in that way, it usually goes inside someplace where you would normally use the schema builder.  Also it doesn't look like you can do raw within a `sum` clause either.  This seems to do what you want by using `raw` inside the `select`:

```
knex('order_item')
  .select(knex.raw('sum(invoice_price * quantity)'))
  .where({cart_session: 'some_session'})
```

This yields the following sql:

```
select sum(invoice_price * quantity) from "order_item" where "cart_session" = 'some_session'
```